# Regular expression to replace with empty string

Tags: c#, regex

I require a regular expression which does following

1. Match if first alphabet of first word in starting line is in
   lowercase .
2. Starting from word containing above alphabet , replace with empty
   string until a word starting with  uppercase occurs

This is what I tried:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input,@"^[a-z]\s?[a-z0-9]\s?[^A-Z]","");
```

This is what should happen:

> Sample input = "of !jgf area. The wealth of nation"
>
> Required Output ="The Wealth of nation"

What should I do to improve/correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do like below:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input,@"^[^A-Z]*","");
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will suffice.

```
^[^A-Z]+
```

It will replace all the characters that is not an upper case letter

By the way there is a **much faster way** without RegEx in C#.

```
int index=str.indexOfAny(new char[] { 'A', 'B', ..., 'Z'})
if(index!=-1){
    str = str.Substring(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
" ([A-Z]+.*)"
```

Use groups, Gruops[1] is what you desired

Comment: Here groups does not add any special value